# Inserir conta com periodo Quinzenal, Mensal, Trimestral, Semestral e Anual

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um script para fazer controle financeiro, nele informo o valor e a quantidade de cada parcela. Gostaria de uma ideia de como poder definir o espaço dessas parcelas para definir se serão parcelas semanais, quinzenais, mensais, trimestrais, semestrais ou anuais. O script que uso hoje gera as parcelas somente mensalmente.

```
include 'conectar.php';

$nParcelas = $_POST['PARCELAS'];
$dataPrimeiraParcela = $_POST['VENCIMENTO'];

function calcularParcelas($nParcelas, $dataPrimeiraParcela = null){
  if($dataPrimeiraParcela != null){
    $dataPrimeiraParcela = explode( "/",$dataPrimeiraParcela);
    $dia = $dataPrimeiraParcela[0];
    $mes = $dataPrimeiraParcela[1]-1;
    $ano = $dataPrimeiraParcela[2];

  } else {
    $dia = date("d");
    $mes = date("m")-1;
    $ano = date("Y");
  }

for($x = 1; $x <= $nParcelas; $x++){
$parcela = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+".$x." month",mktime(0, 0, 0,$mes,$dia,$ano)));
$PAGO = $_POST['PAGO'];
$ID_TIPO = $_POST['ID_TIPO'];
$ID_PESSOA = $_POST['ID_PESSOA'];
$DESCRICAO = $_POST['DESCRICAO'];
$ID_CATEGORIA = $_POST['ID_CATEGORIA'];
$VALOR = $_POST['VALOR'];
$ID_RECEBIMENTO = $_POST['ID_RECEBIMENTO'];
$NP = $x."/".$nParcelas;

   if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO CONTAS
        (ID_TIPO, ID_PESSOA, VENCIMENTO, DESCRICAO, ID_CATEGORIA, VALOR, ID_RECEBIMENTO, PARCELA, ESTADO) 
        VALUES ('".$ID_TIPO."', '".$ID_PESSOA."', '".$parcela."', '".$DESCRICAO."', '".$ID_CATEGORIA."', '".$VALOR."', '".$ID_RECEBIMENTO."', '".$NP."', '".$PAGO."' )"))
  {


    echo "Parcela [".$x."]: ".$parcela."<br/>";

  } else {
    die("Erro ao inserir a parcela ".$x.": ".mysql_error());
  }
}
}
calcularParcelas($nParcelas, $dataPrimeiraParcela);

mysql_close($conexao);
    echo "<a href='conta_nova.php'>Voltar ao sistema</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso num sistema financeiro atualmente para parcelas algo parecido, e faço a adição no MySQL mesmo com a função DATE_ADD, assim `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)`, existe também a DATE_SUB, e claro tu pode colocar isso no teu INSERT

No meu sistema o usuário escolhe na interface dele na hora de inserir e viria um `$_POST['periodicidade']` e eu faço um switch para verificar, por exemplo:

- Quinzenal: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)`
- Mensal: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`
- Trimestral: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)`
- Semestral: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)`
- Anual: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`

E por essa lógica vou inserindo as parcelas cada uma com o vencimento na periodicidade correta